# UL border coming above LI

Tags: css, html-lists

I was working on the below code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="Generate">
  <li>Home1</li>
  <li>Home2</li>
  <li>Home3</li>
  <li>Home4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#Generate {
  list-style-type:none;

  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#Generate > li {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:20px;
}
```

The `UL` border is coming on the top as one solid line. And below that I am seeing one row having the `LI` elements. I was expecting the `UL` border to encompass all the `li` elements. Since it's the parent. Why is the browser shrinking the `ul`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are floating all the li's within the UL. If a container contains only floated elements and nothing is explicitly setting the containers height the resulting height of the container will be zero.

Try adding overflow: auto to your UL:

```
#Generate {
  list-style-type:none;
  overflow: auto;
  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

This URL is a great resource for all things "Float".
Check out the section titled "The Great Collapse".
https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It helped me to understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

you did actualy put the border there by urself :).

```
 #Generate {
 list-style-type:none;

 padding:0px;
 border:1px solid red; <---------border
}
```

so this will do:

```
<style>
#Generate {
list-style-type:none;

padding:0px;
border:0px solid red;
}

#Generate > li {
align:left;
width:9%;
text-align:center;
background-color:red;
color:white;
border:1px solid blue;
height:20px;
}


</style>

<ul id="Generate">
    <li>Home1</li>
    <li>Home2</li>
    <li>Home3</li>
    <li>Home4</li>
</ul>
```

or you just delete that line... but i think you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `float:left`, make it `display:inline`

```
#Generate > li {
  display:inline;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid blue;
  height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO browser shrinks ul because the UL is a flow content category object and as we know from w3c specifications the width of this kind of objects in normal flow calculates as ''margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block' ([W3C site](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth)). So, if you want to ul's border  to encompass only the "li" elements, you may add 'display:inline-block;' in your css rule for #General as mentioned below:

```
  #Generate {
  list-style-type:none;

  padding:0px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uw4krhL1/

Comment: Thanks. Display:inline-block works. But the "ul" is not covering the entire width of the page. So I gave the "display:inline-block " to the "li". And removed the float. This is working.